# How to line break long equation in overleaf keeping both lines left sided, and keeping font-size as well?

Tags: latex, overleaf

My tries:
1st example: I didn't find how to fix the problem with th font size using \begin{array}.
Code:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{l}
    \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}=-R_{z} \cos \delta_{E} \frac{\partial \delta_{E}}{\partial t}-R_{s}\left[-\sin \delta_{E} \frac{\partial \delta_{E}}{\partial t} \cos (\omega t+\lambda-\alpha_{E})+\right. \\
    \left.-\cos \delta_{E} \sin \left(\omega t+\lambda-\alpha_{E}\right)\left(\omega-\frac{\partial \alpha_{E}}{\partial t}\right)\right]
\end{array}
\end{equation}
```

2nd example: Using \begin{split} I didn't find the way the to put second line on the left side.
Code:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    \frac{\partial \Dot{\rho}}{\partial\omega} = -R_{s}A[ A\omega t(\cos{\phi})^2\sin{\delta_{E}}\cos{(\lambda - A\sin{\omega t})} - \omega t\sin{\phi}\sin{(\lambda - A\sin{\omega t})} +\\+ \sin{(\lambda - A\sin{\omega t})}\cos{phi}] - R_{s}At\cos{\phi}\sin{\delta_{E}}\sin{(\lambda - A\sin{\omega t})}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

[Output of the code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTEcG.png)

I also will appreciate a lot if somebody will tell me, that there is a magic command that breaks equation in lines automatically (without manually inserting '\')

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre], not just a code fragement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My favourite way to do this is outlined in section 3.5.2 of [lshort](https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf).
For the sake of everyone, it requires the [IEEEtrantools package](https://ctan.org/pkg/ieeetrantools?lang=en).
The code cited in the sources stated is the following:

```
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
a & = & b + c\\
  & = & d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k \nonumber\\
     && \negmedspace {} + l + m + n + o\\
  & = & p + q + r + s
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
```

Giving the result

[image]

Which you and others should be able to adapt appropriately for their own use case.
The environment defines columns within the equation, which in this case has a right aligned column, followed by centre aligned, followed by left aligned using `{rCl}`.

Note also that generally only one binary operation is used on the second line of a overflowing equation.
And I feel that `\cos{phi}` in the second equation is meant to really be `\cos\phi` as it is elsewhere in your equations.